# Importing a column from 1 Excel sheet to Another and Comparing the Values

Tags: excel, vba, powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm working on a script that basically takes 2 Excel files and will compare the values from a certain column in both files to each other, and will import any differences found to a CSV file named for that day the task was executed.

```cs
function MatrexDiff(){
    # Task is sch to happen daily to find errors
    $action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "MatrexDiff.ps1" -Argument "C:\zach\MatrexDiff.ps1"
    $ trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 5am
    Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "Matrex Differences" -Description "Finds difference between RPM and Matrex Inventories"

    # Makes a txt file than converts txt file to a csv file to hold any differences
    $csv = New-Item -Path "C:\Backup" -Name "Difference" -ItemType file -Force
    $date = (Get-Date).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
    $new = "C:\Data\" + $date + "_Difference.csv"
    $csv | Export-Csv $new

    # imports the lists that will be compared to each other to find and print differences on _Difference .csv file
    $zachPath = "C:\zach\zach.xlsx"
    $tehyaPath = "C:\zach\Tehya.xlsx"

    $xl = New-Object -c excel.application
    $xl.displayAlerts = $false 

    $wb2 = $xl.Workbooks.Open($zachPath, $null, $true) 

    # copys targeted data in the column
    $wb1 = $xl.Workbooks.Open($tehyaPath) 
    $needColumn = $wb1.Sheets.Item('Sheet1') 
    $ColumnToCopy = $needColumn.Range("C1").EnitreColumn

    $ColumnToCopy.Copy

    # paste the copied column into the other excel file
    $sheetToUse = $wb2.Sheets.Item('Sheet1')
    $ColumnToFill = $sheetToUse.Range("C1").EnitreColumn
    $ColumnToFill.Paste($ColumnToCopy) 

    # (poor attempt) exporting the file with the pasted data to Back folder
    $wb2.Close($false) | Export-Csv $wb2
    $wb1.Close($true) 
    $xl.Quit()
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I would convert those excel files to csv and use nested foreach to find differences.

Comment: How would I go about exporting any differences found to another csv files that holds all differences ?

Comment: I would completely step away from fat applications like Excel. PowerShell itself and its cmdlets like   [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-6) and [`Add-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member?view=powershell-6) are much better in achieving things like adding a column with differences.

Comment: You have a typo in the code you posted (`.EnitreColumn` -> `.EntireColumn`). Is that in your original code as well, or just in this question?